# login_redirect for Mobile Web

Tags: redirect, login

I have a mobile version of my website at `mywebsite.com/mobile` and there is a login form which posts to `wp-login.php`.

Currently, when users login from the homepage, they are redirected to their Buddypress profile if they are not admin.
I would like to keep this in place if they login from the home page, but, if they login from `mywebsite.com/mobile`, I would like them to be redirected to `mywebsite.com/mobile/dash`.

```
//REDIRECT USERS TO ACTIVITY PAGE WHEN THEY LOGIN
add_filter( "login_redirect", "bpdev_redirect_to_profile", 10, 3 );

function bpdev_redirect_to_profile( $redirect_to_calculated, $redirect_url_specified, $user )
{
    /* If logging in from website.com/mobile, 
       which has a login form which posts to wp-login.php, 
       redirect to website.com/mobile/dash
    */
    if( empty( $redirect_to_calculated ) )
        $redirect_to_calculated = admin_url();

    /* If the user is not site admin,redirect to his/her profile*/
    if( !is_site_admin( $user->user_login ) )
        return bp_core_get_user_domain( $user->ID );

    /* If site admin or not logged in,do not do anything much */
    else
        return $redirect_to_calculated; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding a conditional check such as,

```
   $current = "http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $mobile = "http://www.example.com/mobile";
    if($current == $mobile) {
        //redirect to desired location
    }
```

I'd provide more detail but am currently on mobile, so it's difficult to write. See how you fair with the above.